# Can't Push Rails Project to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, heroku-postgres

So I've run into a little snag with a rails app that i'm trying to
  deploy on to Heroku. When I attempt to push my app onto Heroku, I'm told
  that rake tasks cannot be detected. In addition, I'm told that the
  application file in the config folder cannot be loaded. I ran this little
  command (bundle exec rake -P RAILS_ENV=production) to see if everything
  in production mode checks out and I don't get  any errors.

I really appreciate anyones help as this is my first time deploying an
  app on Heroku. Thanks!

```
Total 7266 (delta 1071), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.

List item

remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.2.
remote: -----> Installing dependencies using bundler 1.11.2
remote:        Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
remote:        Installing i18n 0.7.0
remote:        Installing json 1.8.3 with native extensions
remote:        Installing rake 11.1.2
remote:        Installing minitest 5.8.4
remote:        Installing thread_safe 0.3.5
remote:        Installing builder 3.2.2
remote:        Installing erubis 2.7.0
remote:        Installing mini_portile2 2.0.
remote:        Installing rack 1.6.4
remote:        Installing mime-types-data 3.2016.0221
remote:        Installing arel 6.0.3
remote:        Installing execjs 2.6.0
remote:        Installing bcrypt 3.1.11 with native extensions
remote:        Installing sass 3.4.22
remote:        Installing coffee-script-source 1.10.0
remote:        Installing thor 0.19.1
remote:        Installing concurrent-ruby 1.0.1
remote:        Installing orm_adapter 0.5.0
remote:        Installing multi_json 1.11.2
remote:        Installing pg 0.18.4 with native extensions
remote:        Using bundler 1.11.2
remote:        Installing rails_serve_static_assets 0.0.5
remote:        Installing rails_stdout_logging 0.0.5
remote:        Installing tilt 2.0.2
remote:        Installing tzinfo 1.2.2
remote:        Installing nokogiri 1.6.7.2 with native extensions
remote:        Installing rack-test 0.6.3
remote:        Installing warden 1.2.6
remote:        Installing mime-types 3.0
remote:        Installing autoprefixer-rails 6.3.5
remote:        Installing uglifier 3.0.0
remote:        Installing coffee-script 2.4.
remote:        Installing sprockets 3.5.2
remote:        Installing rails_12factor 0.0.3
remote:        Installing mail 2.6.4
remote:        Installing bootstrap-sass 3.3.6
remote:        Installing loofah 2.0.3
remote:        Installing rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.3
remote:        Installing activesupport 4.2.
remote:        Installing rdoc 4.2.2
remote:        Installing rails-deprecated_sanitizer 1.0.3
remote:        Installing globalid 0.3.6
remote:        Installing activemodel 4.2.5
remote:        Installing jbuilder 2.4.1
remote:        Installing activejob 4.2.5
remote:        Installing rails-dom-testing 1.0.7
remote:        Installing activerecord 4.2.5
remote:        Installing actionview 4.2.5
remote:        Installing actionpack 4.2.5
remote:        Installing sdoc 0.4.1
remote:        Installing actionmailer 4.2.5
remote:        Installing railties 4.2.5
remote:        Installing sprockets-rails 3.0.4
remote:        Installing coffee-rails 4.1.1
remote:        Installing responders 2.1.2
remote:        Installing jquery-rails 4.1.1
remote:        Installing rails 4.2.5
remote:        Installing sass-rails 5.0.4
remote:        Installing turbolinks 2.5.3
remote:        Installing devise 3.5.6
remote:        Bundle complete! 15 Gemfile dependencies, 60 gems now installed.
remote:        Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
remote:        Bundled gems are installed into ./vendor/bundle.
remote:        Post-install message from rdoc:
remote:        Depending on your version of ruby, you may need to install ruby rdoc/ri data:
remote:        <= 1.8.6 : unsupported
remote:        = 1.8.7 : gem install rdoc-data; rdoc-data --install
remote:        = 1.9.1 : gem install rdoc-data; rdoc-data --install
remote:        >= 1.9.2 : nothing to do! Yay
remote:        Bundle completed (22.56s)
remote:        Cleaning up the bundler cache
remote: sh: 2: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
remote: sh: 2: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
remote:  !
remote:  !     Could not detect rake tasks
remote:  !     ensure you can run `$ bundle exec rake -P` against your app
remote:  !     and using the production group of your Gemfile.
remote:  !     rake aborted!
remote:  !     LoadError: cannot load such file -- /tmp/build_81c00152de97c61281a1204214d29edb/website/config/application
remote:  !     /tmp/build_81c00152de97c61281a1204214d29edb/website/Rakefile:4:in `require
remote:  !     /tmp/build_81c00152de97c61281a1204214d29edb/website/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_81c00152de97c61281a1204214d29edb/website/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load'
```

Comment: Does your app run locally?

Comment: Yep and perfectly!

Comment: If you run "heroku config" from the command line, are your environment variables sane - i.e. no mismatched quotes?

Comment: The following is my output after running heroku config:                                === enigmatic-reaches-49643 Config Vars