# Pushing Rails to Heroku, can't find Rake taks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

UPDATE: now using Ruby 2.5.5  and Bundler 2.0.2, still getting the error:

```
/app/tmp/buildpacks/<long hash>/lib/language_pack/helpers/rake_runner.rb:106:
in load_rake_tasks!': 
Could not detect rake tasks (LanguagePack::Helpers::RakeRunner::CannotLoadRakefileError)`
```

I'm trying to `git push heroku master` a Rails app for the first time, and I'm getting this error:

```
remote: -----> Detecting rake tasks
remote:
remote: !
remote: ! Could not detect rake tasks
remote: ! ensure you can run `$ bundle exec rake -P` against your app
remote: ! and using the production group of your Gemfile.
remote: ! Activating bundler (2.0.1) failed:
remote: ! Could not find 'bundler' (2.0.1) required by your /tmp/build_cf9981ccbdc1fd4f0b82703a5ff40ecc/Gemfile.lock.
remote: ! To update to the latest version installed on your system, run `bundle update --bundler`.
remote: ! To install the missing version, run `gem install bundler:2.0.1`
remote: ! Checked in 'GEM_PATH=vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0', execute `gem env` for more information
remote: !
remote: ! To install the version of bundler this project requires, run `gem install bundler -v '2.0.1'`
remote: !
remote: /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/helpers/rake_runner.rb:106:in `load_rake_tasks!': Could not detect rake tasks (LanguagePack::Helpers::RakeRunner::CannotLoadRakefileError)
remote: ensure you can run `$ bundle exec rake -P` against your app
remote: and using the production group of your Gemfile.
remote: Activating bundler (2.0.1) failed:
remote: Could not find 'bundler' (2.0.1) required by your /tmp/build_cf9981ccbdc1fd4f0b82703a5ff40ecc/Gemfile.lock.
remote: To update to the latest version installed on your system, run `bundle update --bundler`.
remote: To install the missing version, run `gem install bundler:2.0.1`
remote: Checked in 'GEM_PATH=vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0', execute `gem env` for more information
remote:
remote: To install the version of bundler this project requires, run `gem install bundler -v '2.0.1'`
```

I have run `gem install bundler:2.0.1` successfully in this app's root directory. My `$GEM_PATH` does not include `vendor/bundle/ruby/2`, and I don't know if altering it is the solution. If so, does that mean I need to alter it locally or remotely? If locally, is it done the same way as normal environment variables, or is there a special Rails setting I need to change?

I have tried the suggestion in the accepted answer here:

[heroku push error: "Could not detect rake tasks"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36394297/heroku-push-error-could-not-detect-rake-tasks)

but that made no difference.

My problem also seems to be similar to the (unanswered) question here:

[Can't Push Rails Project to Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36322341/cant-push-rails-project-to-heroku)

Searching the Heroku Help Center didn't seem to yield any results, either.

Any guidance about what I should do?

Comment: Did you run "bundle exec rake -P" as suggested in the logs?

Comment: What are the logs of the deploy is saying after you tried `gem install bundler:2.0.1`?

Comment: What buildpacks are used by the app?

Comment: Akhil: Yes, I have done this. Despite getting no error messages when I run those commands, I get the same error messages again when I try to run `git push` again.

Comment: Simon: the logs appear identical before and after running `gem install bundler:2.0.1`. (There may be some difference in the hash digest values, but I can't tell those by eye and didn't run a diff, and everything else appears the same.)

Comment: Simon: the log reports `Detected buildpacks: Ruby,Node.js`

Comment: @Simon Franzen: Just using a (so far as I can tell) vanilla `heroku/ruby` buildpack.

Answer (score 0):

This is a [known issue with Bundler 2 on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler-version#known-upgrade-issues):

> A Gemfile.lock that specifies bundler 2.0.2 does not work with bundler 2.0.1
>
> If you attempt to deploy an app that uses bundler 2.0.2 onto the Heroku platform with bundler 2.0.1 you may get this error:
>
> ```
> `find_spec_for_exe': can't find gem bundler (>= 0.a) with executable bundle (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
> ```
>
> This is due to a bug in the Rubygems bundler version checking code. To avoid this issue, upgrade your Ruby version. It is fixed in 2.5.5+ and 2.6.3+. If you do not update, your Ruby version then every new release of Bundler 2.x will trigger this issue.

Upgrade Ruby to version 2.5.5+ or 2.6.3+ locally, update your `Gemfile` accordingly, and re-run `bundle`. Commit the changes to your `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock`, then deploy again.

Comment: Chris: Thanks, but even after doing that, I still can't push to Heroku. It still complains about not being able to detect rake tasks, then runs what appears to be a series of rake tasks, then complains, after a 'rake yarn install' attempt, of an 'invalid option: -P', which I have never specified and don't know where it comes from.

Comment: @amp108, I'm pretty sure this the problem. What version of Ruby is Heroku using when it tries to build your application? (For comparison, the output you show above shows `ruby/2.5.0`, which is a version affected by the issue I linked to.)

Comment: yes, I updated after asking the question, and now, even though the log says `remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.5.5` and `remote: -----> Installing dependencies using bundler 2.0.2`, I'm still getting `remote: /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/helpers/rake_runner.rb:106:in `load_rake_tasks!': Could not detect rake tasks (LanguagePack::Helpers::RakeRunner::CannotLoadRakefileError)`

Comment: Please update your question with this new information, including more context for that error message.